Inverse Dynamics for a Control Moment Gyroscope (CMG) System
I am trying to design a control moment gyroscope (CMG) system that can produce the specific torque asked for.
The system is a 2-DoF gimbal equipped with a flywheel. The flywheel's angular velocity is denoted by $\dot{\rho}$, the first stage of the gimbal is yaw ${\psi}$, and the second stage is pitch ${\theta}$.
Here is a diagram of the system:

It is modeled with this:
\begin{gather}
  \vec{M}_{\text{gyro}, A} = 
  \begin{pmatrix}
  \frac{1}{4} I \left( 2 \overset{\cdot}{\theta} \overset{\cdot}{\rho} - \overset{\cdot \cdot}{\psi} \sin \theta \right) \\
  \frac{1}{4} I \left( \overset{\cdot \cdot}{\theta} + \overset{\cdot}{\psi} \sin \theta \left( 2 \overset{\cdot}{\rho} + 
  \overset{\cdot}{\psi} \cos \theta \right) \right) \\
  \frac{1}{2} I \left( \overset{\cdot \cdot}{\rho} + \overset{\cdot \cdot}{\psi} \cos \theta - \overset{\cdot}{\theta} \overset{\cdot}{\psi} 
  \sin \theta \right)
  \end{pmatrix}
\end{gather}
$\vec{M}_{\text{gyro}, A}$ is the total torque generated by the system, based on the variables: $\theta$, $\psi$, $\overset{\cdot}{\theta}$, $\overset{\cdot}{\psi}$, $\overset{\cdot}{\rho}$, $\overset{\cdot \cdot}{\theta}$, $\overset{\cdot \cdot}{\psi}$, $\overset{\cdot \cdot}{\rho}$
Given a desired torque of $\vec{M}_{\text{gyro}, A}$, it is impossible to find an exact mathematical solution as there are eight variables with only three equations. The variables $\ddot{\theta}$, $\ddot{\psi}$, $\ddot{\rho}$ can be directly manipulated by controlling the power input to the motors (of the gimbal and flywheel), therefore I need to design a control strategy that achieves a wanted torque by adjusting the angular accelerations.
Potential Solution:
Treating $\theta$, $\psi$, $\overset{\cdot}{\theta}$, $\overset{\cdot}{\psi}$, $\overset{\cdot}{\rho}$ as constant would enable us to find a solution for $\ddot{\theta}$, $\ddot{\psi}$, $\ddot{\rho}$ in terms of $\vec{M}_{\text{gyro}, A}$. The variables $\theta$, $\psi$, $\overset{\cdot}{\theta}$, $\overset{\cdot}{\psi}$, $\overset{\cdot}{\rho}$ can be sampled real-time and the corresponding angular accelerations can be found with the following formulas:
\begin{gather}
\ddot{\rho} = \frac{2\vec{M}_{z}}{I} + \dot{\theta}\dot{\psi} \sin(\theta) - \cos(\theta) \left( \frac{2\dot{\theta}\dot{\rho}}{\sin(\theta)} - \frac{4\vec{M}_{x}}{I\sin(\theta)} \right)
\end{gather}
\begin{gather}
\ddot{\psi} = \frac{2\dot{\theta}\dot{\rho}}{\sin(\theta)} - \frac{4\vec{M}_{x}}{I\sin(\theta)}
\end{gather}
\begin{gather}
\ddot{\theta} = \frac{4\vec{M}_{y}}{I} - \dot{\psi} \sin(\theta) \left( \dot{\psi} \cos(\theta) + 2\dot{\rho} \right)
\end{gather}
Problem 1: The angular accelerations are proportional to the current angular velocities. That being said, if I attempt to maintain a constant output torque, the required accelerations will escalate indefinitely as each correction step increases the angular velocities further in subsequent iterations. Certainly, it will diverge almost immediately.
Problem 2: The equations contain terms of the form $\frac{1}{\sin(\theta)}$, which does not exist when $\theta = 0, \pi$. How can I solve the divide-by-zero issues?
I need an advanced control algorithm that takes these factors into account (I don't think a simple PID will be able to handle this). I would really appreciate any suggestions or help.

I have no experience or expertise in engineering or designing CMG systems, so this might be a basic question.

